# Python multiprocessing slower than simple pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I have a 1.4GB file (around 20M lines) to read and compute. At first I just want to apply a filter on it. Moreover I want to use multiprocessing in order to speed up my algorithm.

To do this I use pandas on linux. I have 32GB memory...

The problem is that my algorithms using python multiprocessing are slower than the normal one and I can't understand why, I think I miss something !

- Iterative algorithm :

```
%%time
my_data = pd.read_csv(filenames['my_file'], chunksize=chunk_size)



res = np.array([])
for chunk in my_data : 
    res = np.append(res,chunk[(chunk['field1']=='field1') |
                          (chunk['field2']=='field2')])
```

```
CPU times: user 1min 12s, sys: 2.27 s, total: 1min 14s
Wall time: 1min 14s
```

- Python multiprocessing algorithm :

```
def function(df) :
    return df[(df['field1']=='field1') |
              (df['field2']=='field2')]
%%time
my_data = pd.read_csv(filenames['my_file'], chunksize=chunk_size)

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
funclist = []
res = np.array([])

for chunk in my_data : 
    # process each data frame
    f = pool.apply_async(function,[chunk])
    funclist.append(f)

for f in funclist:
    res = np.append(res, f.get(timeout=10)) # timeout in 10 seconds

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

```
CPU times: user 1min 51s, sys: 6.65 s, total: 1min 58s
Wall time: 1min 54s
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is a lot of overhead in python multiprocessing, and pandas is fairly optimized (some C computation under the hood). You could use [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) it offers parallelized dataframes in python, might be faster.

Comment: They are not doing the same thing. You are iterating through your data twice in the multiprocessing.

Comment: You shouldn't be appending to numpy arrays. They are not great at changing size. Your original code needs work before you turn to multiprocessing but it's unclear to me what output you want

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes just append the result for each chunk to a list and then concatenate at the end. For the multiprocessing case, you can just do `res = np.concatenate(pool.map(function, my_data), axis=0)`. (also it is recommended to use the process pool as a context manager to ensure it is closed cleanly even if there are exceptions)

Comment: Thank you all for your response, I tried the ```res = np.concatenate(pool.map(function, my_data), axis=0)``` and have the same result as with the ```f = pool.apply_async(function,[chunk])```... I changed the numpy arrays but it's not the problem, I do it in both algorithms. The output I want is just the lines correct according to my filter ! I tried dask and the execution is a bit faster in wall time : 1min 3s but my CPU time is a lot faster : 6.69s !